# Can't connect to pre-configured NAS boxes with static addresses and default gateway 172.16.2.1

Tags: ubuntu, network-attached-storage, gateway, ip-routing, virtual-network

I received several TeraStation NAS boxes which I can't configure because I can't connect to them, presumably because they were setup for a specific environment. I'm hoping to virtualize the environment needed to properly connect to them. I have them all connected to a 16-port switch. My Ubuntu desktop has 2 NICs, one with my internet and the other unused. I have a Ubuntu laptop with virtualbox if I need it. The NAS boxes are configured as such:

IP: 172.16.2.20X

netmask: 255.255.255.0

gateway:172.16.2.1

I tried to have my eth1 be 172.16.2.1 and added that as a route, but no such luck. I need to access the webpages of 172.16.2.201..207 to make the proper networking changes. How do I setup my eth1 or a VM such that I can reach these hosts?

Edited to amend information:

```
root@host:/root# ifconfig eth1


eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:a7:90:30  
      inet addr:172.16.2.199  Bcast:172.16.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fg80::3285:a9gf:feg7:9030/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:431108 (431.1 KB)  TX bytes:416593 (416.5 KB)
      Interrupt:19 Memory:d3200000-d3220000 


root@host:/root# ping 172.16.2.204
PING 172.16.2.204 (172.16.2.204) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.2.199 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.2.199 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.2.199 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.16.2.204 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4024ms
pipe 3
root@host:/root# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         XXX.NNN.89.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
XXX.NNN.89.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
172.16.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a static route or gateway.  Adding the 172.16.2.X interface on Ubuntu with the correct netmask should be enough to connect.  I'd suggest removing the gateway for the interface and let the built-in network routing attempt to handle it.

If this doesn't work, you may want to check the output of:

```
netstat -rn
```

to see if you have any strange or overriding routes for that private network.  You can also attempt a ping or traceroute, to make sure the old NAS units are even present on the network, before trying to hit them via a browser.

Comment: After your recommendation, I've set the eth1 to be 172.16.2.199 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0 and the pings say Destination Host Unreachable. I've edit my question to show the routes and ping info.